# How to count number or rectangles in a 2D array with Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, image, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have an array. I wish to identify a rectangles top-left and bottom-right point. This is easy with a single rectangle. See my implementation below.
The problem becomes challenging when there are multiple rectangles. How do you identify top-left and bottom-right points with multiple rectangles?

## rules continuous 0's are rectangles: In the below example there are 3 rectangles.

```
array = [
[1,1,1,1,0,0],
[1,0,1,1,0,0],
[1,0,1,1,0,0],
[1,1,0,0,1,1],
[1,1,0,0,1,1]]

def parse_array(arr)
   answer = []
  arr.each_with_index do |sub_array, x|
    sub_array.each_with_index do |number, y|
        if number == 0
            answer.push([x,y])
        end
    end
  end
  answer
end

def edges(arr)
  [arr.first, arr.last]
end

def get_length_and_width(arr)
  width = (arr[1][1] - arr[0][1]) + 1
  height = (arr[1][0] - arr[0][0]) + 1
  [width, height]
end
```

Comment: For your example, `parse_array(array) #=> [[0, 4], [0, 5], [1, 1], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 1], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 2], [3, 3], [4, 2], [4, 3]]`. Please explain what this means and also clarify "continuous 0's are rectangles". Please do that by editing your answer rather than in a comment. (All comments are not read by all readers.)

Comment: I updated the question, sorry for the late response I got busy at work! The above example has 3 rectangle groups. The first group is [[0,4], [2,5]] the second is [[1,1],[2,1]] and the last is [[3,2], [4,3]]. where [[top left], [bottom right]] is how encoded the info

Comment: What is the desired result when `array = [[0,0], [0,1]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic idea:

- Deep-clone the array so we don't mess it up
- Find a top-left corner of a rectangle
- See how high it goes
- See how wide it goes
- Fill it up so we don't find those spaces any more
- Repeat till no zeroes remain

So...

```
class RectFinder < Array
  def initialize(array)
    super()
    @a = array.map { |x| x.dup }
    @h = array.size
    @w = array.first.size
    find_rects
  end

  private def find_rects
    (0...@h).each do |r|
      (0...@w).each do |c|
        if @a[r][c] == 0
          self << find_rect(r, c)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private def find_rect(r, c)
    w = ((c + 1)...@w).take_while { |cc| @a[r][cc] == 0 }.size + 1
    h = ((r + 1)...@h).take_while { |rr| (c...(c + w)).all? { |cc| @a[rr][cc] == 0 } }.size + 1
    (r...(r + h)).each { |rr| @a[rr][c...(c + w)] = [1] * w }
    [[r, c], [r + h - 1, c + w - 1]]
  end
end

p RectFinder.new(array)
# => [[[0, 4], [2, 5]], [[1, 1], [2, 1]], [[3, 2], [4, 3]]]
```

Comment: Nice job! There's a small difference between our assumptions. if `array =  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]`, you return `[[[0, 0], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [3, 0]]]`, which gives a row bias, whereas I return `[[[0, 0], [0, 2]], [[0, 0], [3, 0]]]`,     which overlap `[0,0]`.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the question is, when a given array with `n` elements ("rows"), each element being an array of `m` elements ("columns") is viewed as a matrix, construct an array of all submatrices that contain only zeroes, where each submatrix is identified by the coordinates of its upper-left and lower-right elements. For example, the elements `array[1][4]`, `array[1][5]`, `array[2][4]` and `array[2][5]`, which all equal zero, comprise a submatrix identified by the pair of coordinates `[[1,4],[2,5]]`.

```
require 'matrix'

def all_zero_subarrays(arr)
  m = Matrix[*arr]
  last_row, last_col = arr.size-1, arr.first.size-1
  (0..last_row).each_with_object([]) do |i,a|
    (0..last_col).each do |j|
      next unless arr[i][j].zero?
      (i..last_row).each do |ii|
        (j..last_col).each do |jj|
          next unless arr[ii][jj].zero?
          a << [[i,j], [ii,jj]] if m.minor((i..ii), (j..jj)).to_a.flatten.uniq == [0]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

array = [
  [1,1,1,1,0,0],
  [1,0,1,1,0,0],
  [1,0,1,1,0,0],
  [1,1,0,0,1,1],
  [1,1,0,1,1,1]]
```

I changed `array[4][3]` from `0` to `1`, `array` having been defined in the question. My reason for doing so will be made clear later.

```
arr = all_zero_subarrays(array)
  #=> [[[0, 4], [0, 4]], [[0, 4], [0, 5]], [[0, 4], [1, 4]], [[0, 4], [1, 5]],
  #    [[0, 4], [2, 4]], [[0, 4], [2, 5]], [[0, 5], [0, 5]], [[0, 5], [1, 5]],
  #    [[0, 5], [2, 5]],
  #    [[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [2, 1]], [[1, 4], [1, 4]], [[1, 4], [1, 5]],
  #    [[1, 4], [2, 4]], [[1, 4], [2, 5]], [[1, 5], [1, 5]], [[1, 5], [2, 5]],
  #    [[2, 1], [2, 1]], [[2, 4], [2, 4]], [[2, 4], [2, 5]], [[2, 5], [2, 5]],
  #    [[3, 2], [3, 2]], [[3, 2], [3, 3]], [[3, 2], [4, 2]], [[3, 3], [3, 3]],
  #    [[4, 2], [4, 2]]]
```

See [Matrix::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-5B-5D) and [Matrix#minor](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-minor).

If desired, elements of `arr` that represent submatrices that are "contained" in another submatrix can be removed. For example, `[[0, 4], [1, 5]]` is "contained in `[[0, 4], [2, 5]]`. Here is a way of doing that.

```
def second_rect_in_first?(rect1, rect2)
  ul1, br1 = rect1
  ul2, br2 = rect2
  first_ul_of_second?(ul1, ul2) && first_ul_of_second?(br2, br1)
end

def first_ul_of_second?((i1, j1), (i2, j2))
  (i1 <= i2) && (j1 <= j2)
end

arr.each_with_object([]) do |rect, a|
  next if a.any? { |arect| second_rect_in_first?(arect, rect) } 
  a.reject! { |arect| second_rect_in_first?(rect, arect) } 
  a << rect  
end
  #=> [[[0, 4], [2, 5]],
  #    [[1, 1], [2, 1]],
  #    [[3, 2], [3, 3]],
  #    [[3, 2], [4, 2]]]
```

Note that `[[3, 2], [3, 3]]` and `[[3, 2], [4, 2]]]` both include `[3, 2]`.

Comment: I modified my answer to provide the required information.